# Is there a way to get static buffer field's name by static reference?

Tags: buffer, field, openedge, progress-4gl

I know there's way to get static buffer's table name with this:

```
DEF BUFFER Customer_B1 FOR Customer.

DEF VAR cTableName AS CHAR NO-UNDO.

cTableName = BUFFER Customer_B1:HANDLE:TABLE.
```

**Is there a similar way to get `buffer field handle` and it's field name using static reference?**

I would like to use `static buffers` because they are checked at compile time against the configured database. This means that if some table or field is missing, the codes won't compile. **I wouldn't like to use field number or string names to get the field handle.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in a static way (e.g. with compile time check for the field name).

```
ASSIGN cName     = BUFFER Customer_B1:BUFFER-FIELD ("CustNum"):NAME
       cDataType = BUFFER Customer_B1:BUFFER-FIELD ("CustNum"):DATA-TYPE .
```

By the way, in your sample above, you can leave out the :HANDLE bit:

```
cTableName = BUFFER Customer_B1:TABLE.
```